# How to get the base class name of a class via Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/) and I have the following class:

```
var source = @"
    using System;
    class MyClass : MyBaseClass {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
      }
    }";

// Parsing
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

// This uses an internal function (working)
// That gets the first node of type `SimpleBaseTypeSyntax`
SimpleBaseTypeSyntax simpleBaseType = GetNBaseClassNode(tree);
```

### Getting the base class name

I successfully get access to node `SimpleBaseTypeSyntax` which contains what I need. In fact, if I use the syntax explorer, I get:

[image]

Node `IdentifierToken` has everything I need has its `Text`, `Value` and `ValueText` properties are `"MyBaseClass"`!

However, while in the syntax explorer I can see all these values, I cannot access them programmatically.

So I try retrieving the node programmatically:

```
IdentifierNameSyntax identifierNode =
  simpleBaseType.ChildNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().First();
SyntaxToken identifier = simpleBaseType.Identifier;
string name = identifier.Text;
```

But `name` is empty string. Same as `identifier.Value` and `identifier.ValueText`.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I am doing wrong, so **how would you retrieve the base class name?**

---

#### Another attempt: Using the semantic model

I started thinking that I need the semantic model for this type of information:

```
IdentifierNameSyntax identifierNode =
  simpleBaseType .ChildNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().First();

SemanticModel semanticModel =
  CSharpCompilation.Create("Class")
   .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
     typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
       .AddSyntaxTrees(tree).GetSemanticModel(tree);

SymbolInfo symbolInfo = this.semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierNode);
string name = symbolInfo.Symbol.Name;
```

This throws exception as `symbolInfo.Symbol` is `null`.

Comment: First of all, you probably want the semantic model.

Comment: If you call GetDiagnostics() on your created compilation object, are there any errors present? If something is setup wrong you might not get any binding information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I actually don't know why you can't pass the `BaseTypeSyntax` to the semantic model via `GetSymbolInfo()`, but it's also returning `null` for me with no errors.

Anyways, here's an approach that works:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System;
class MyBaseClass
{
}
class MyClass : MyBaseClass {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
  }
}");

var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

var myClass = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Last();
var myClassSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(myClass) as ITypeSymbol;
var baseTypeName = myClassSymbol.BaseType.Name;
```

You'll want to use the semantic model here because you won't be able to reliably tell if you're dealing with an interface or a base type at the syntax level.

Comment: "var myClassSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(myClass) as ITypeSymbol;" Changes to ISymbol now require a cast

Answer (score 5):

I can see that you're trying to build an analyzer with the Roslyn API.
You do know that there are other ways to test your analyzer logic? Using unit test files instead of directly having the source inside the analyzer.

Using this idea, you entirely build your analyzer with the template provided by Visual Studio, where you must inherit from DiagnosticAnalyzer and you create your analysis code logic.

For your situation, you should look at ClassDeclaration and easily access the BaseTypes property inside the Node.

```
        public bool SomeTriedDiagnosticMethod(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext nodeContext)
    {
        var classDeclarationNode = nodeContext.Node as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
        if (classDeclarationNode == null) return false;
        var baseType = classDeclarationNode.BaseList.Types.FirstOrDefault(); //  Better use this in all situations to be sure code won't break
        var nameOfFirstBaseType = baseType.Type.ToString();  
        return nameOfFirstBaseType == "BaseType";

    }
```

Comment: I want to get syntax trees in both if these classes  :JsonPropertyAccess<StylesheetDto>; Do you know how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected static bool IsWebPage(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
    {
        INamedTypeSymbol iSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) as INamedTypeSymbol;
        INamedTypeSymbol symbolBaseType = iSymbol?.BaseType;

        while (symbolBaseType != null)
        {
            if (symbolBaseType.ToString() == "System.Web.UI.Page")
                return true;
            symbolBaseType = symbolBaseType.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my helper class that finds all properties, class name, class namespace and base classes.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class CsharpClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public List<CsharpProperty> Properties { get; set; }
        public List<string> BaseClasses { get; set; }

        public class CsharpProperty
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }

            public CsharpProperty(string name, string type)
            {
                Name = name;
                Type = type;
            }
        }

        public CsharpClass()
        {
            Properties = new List<CsharpProperty>();
            BaseClasses = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public static class CsharpClassParser
    {
        public static CsharpClass Parse(string content)
        {
            var csharpClass = new CsharpClass();
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(content);
            var members = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();

            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                if (member is PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
                {
                    csharpClass.Properties.Add(new CsharpClass.CsharpProperty(
                        property.Identifier.ValueText, property.Type.ToString()));
                }

                if (member is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclaration)
                {
                    csharpClass.Namespace = namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString();
                }

                if (member is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
                {
                    csharpClass.Name = classDeclaration.Identifier.ValueText;

                    csharpClass.BaseClasses = GetBaseClasses(classDeclaration).ToList();
                }

                //if (member is MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("Method: " + method.Identifier.ValueText);
                //}
            }

            return csharpClass;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetBaseClasses(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
        {
            if (classDeclaration == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (classDeclaration.BaseList == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return classDeclaration.BaseList.Types.Select(x => x.Type.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
const string content = @"
namespace Acme.Airlines.AirCraft
{
    public class AirCraft
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual int Code { get; set; }

        public AirCraft()
        {

        }
    }
}";

var csharpClass = CsharpClassParser.Parse(content);

Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Name);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Namespace);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Properties.Count);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.BaseClasses.Count);
```